# Punctuation between authors in bibliography?

Tags: bibtex, punctuation, custom-bib

I am finalizing my doctoral dissertation in LaTeX, and before printing my university has some very specific requirements regarding the formatting of the references section. Using `makebst` I have been able to reproduce most of them, but one thing has me baffled.

My university requires that author names be separated by dashes, like so:

> Feeny, David F. – Willcocks, Leslie P. (1998) Core IS capabilities for
>   exploiting information technology. *Sloan Management Review*, Vol. 39
>   (3), 9–21.

How can I edit my custom `.bst` file so that it will separate authors by `-` instead of by commas?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your question was migrated here from another stackexchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 11):

If you're willing to switch to [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex), here's a solution that uses en-dashes as name separators (and meets your other formatting requirements for the `article` entry type):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\usepackage{xpatch}

% Last name always before first name for authors
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}

% Unbreakable space -- en-dash -- space as separator between author names
\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{~--\space}
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{~--\space}

% No period after year
\xapptobibmacro{date+extrayear}{%
  \nopunct
}{}{}

% Titles of articles not inside quotation marks
\DeclareFieldFormat
    [article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]{title}{#1}

% No "In: " before journal titles of articles
\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
    \ifentrytype{article}{}{\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}

% Comma before volume of articles
\xpretobibmacro{volume+number+eid}{%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
}{}{}

% "Volume" capitalized for articles
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{\bibsentence\bibstring{volume}~#1}

% Unbreakable space instead of dot before number of articles
\xpatchbibmacro{volume+number+eid}{%
  \setunit*{\adddot}%
}{%
  \setunit*{\addnbspace}%
}{}{}

% Number of articles in parentheses
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

% No prefix for pages
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Fee98,
  author = {Feeny, David F. and Willcocks, Leslie P.},
  year = {1998},
  title = {Core IS capabilities for exploiting information technology},
  journaltitle = {Sloan Management Review},
  volume = {39},
  number = {3},
  pages = {9--21},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

See also [Guidelines for customizing biblatex styles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12806/guidelines-for-customizing-biblatex-styles).